# Bit bang DATA and CLOCK synchronisation issue

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm attempting to bit bang a sequence of data from an ATSAME70Q21 to a series of shift registers (TLC5971 LED drivers). My production hardware will likely make use of hardware SPI for this purpose, but my current prototype is making use of GPIO pins so I'd like to use bit banging.

I'm fairly comfortable in arranging the data in the correct sequence as per the TLC5971 datasheet, and in shifting each bit at a time. I have an oscilloscope connected to both the DATA (BBDAT) and CLOCK (BBCLK) lines, which has illustrated something not quite right with the function.

If I simply toggle each of the BBDAT and BBCLK lines HIGH and then immediately LOW again, I get a very stable 1.85MHz signal on both lines on the oscilloscope. However, when I loop through the data structure, setting DATA either HIGH or LOW depending on the bit value, and then toggling CLOCK HIGH/LOW, the resulting signal frequency on BBDAT is around an order of magnitude lower than that of BBCLK. Given that I only toggle BBCLK once at the end of each BBDAT set/clear, I'm not sure why this would be the case.

```
void writeData(void)
{
    Pio *baseData = (Pio *)(uintptr_t)PIOD;
    Pio *baseClock = (Pio *)(uintptr_t)PIOB;

    //I have 3 TLC5971 ICs in series, hence i < 3
    for (uint i = 0, i < 3; i++) {

        //Each packet for each TLC5971 IC is 28 bytes long
        for (uint j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
            for (uint k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                if (dataPacket[i][j] & (1 << k)) {

                    //If bit is 1, Set DATA line (BBDAT)
                    baseData->PIO_SODR = 1U << (BBDAT & 0x1F);
                } else {

                    //If bit is 0, Clear DATA line (BBDAT)
                    baseData->PIO_CODR = 1U << (BBDAT & 0x1F);
                }

                //Toggle the CLOCK line (BBCLK)
                baseClock->PIO_SODR = 1U << (BBCLK & 0x1F);
                baseClock->PIO_CODR = 1U << (BBCLK & 0x1F);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code (with no optimisation) produces a BBDAT signal of ~100kHz and a BBCLK signal of ~1.4MHz. What am I missing here?

Comment: The number of BBDAT edges would depend on the number of transitions within the data, what sort of pattern is the data?

Comment: It's probably easiest to point you to the relevant section in the TLC5971 datasheet (page 23): http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5971.pdf

Comment: Point taken though. I've established that the baseline signals are as expected, so I should probably focus on getting the data structure and sequencing correct.